# Beautiful Soup can't make the difference between CSS class

Tags: css, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrap Href from this [page](http://m.zooplus.co.uk/shop/pet_food/royal_canin_food/rc_size_dog).

There a two types of product. Those highlighted and those who aren't. I want the latter. 
The CSS class associated with those product aren't the same. That's why i tried to used them.

I just tried here to output the `li` i was interested in for the moment.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from collections import *
from statistics import mean

list_url=[]

url = 'http://m.zooplus.co.uk/shop/pet_food/royal_canin_food/rc_size_dog'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

product_list = soup.find_all("li", {"class":"list-item"})
for elem in product_list:
    print("////////////////BEGIN//////////")
    print(elem)
    print("///////////////END/////////////")
```

Output :

```
<li class="list-item highlighted">
```

That's the kind product i don't want.

And as well :

```
<li class="list-item ">
```

That's the product i want.

Has beautiful soup the same look on a `<li class="list-item ">`and a `<li class="list-item highlighted">` ?

What did i miss ?

EDIT for Yogi :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from collections import *
from statistics import mean

list_url=[]

url = 'http://m.zooplus.co.uk/shop/pet_food/royal_canin_food/rc_size_dog'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
product_list = soup.find_all("li", {"class":"list-item","id": lambda L: L !="special"})
for elem in product_list:
    print("////////////////BEGIN//////////")
    print(elem)
    print("///////////////END/////////////")
```

Comment: Class list-items finds all elements with that class, even if they also have other classes...

Comment: I really don't understand. For me `class="list-item highlighted"` and `class="list-item "` are clearly two difference classes.

Comment: The `class` _attributes_ may be different, but both elements do have class `list-item`. Sorry, but that's just how it is. "list-item highlighted" is not ***a class***, it's a collection of 2 classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, this is what you mean:
[image: Highlighted/Not Highlighted]

This works:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from collections import *
from statistics import mean
import time
import re



list_url=[]

url = 'http://m.zooplus.co.uk/shop/pet_food/royal_canin_food/rc_size_dog'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
rows = soup.find_all('li',{'class':re.compile('list-item.*')})


for row in rows:
    cls=row.attrs.get("class")
    if not ("highlighted" in cls):
        print(row.text)
```